# update a set of numbers to html tags with ajax+jquery from a php file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get several piece of code for updating some sets of numbers on a html web page with ajax+jquery from a php file that displays the number that i want to be shown in html.

php file gets statistic numbers from database, preferably in arrays.( i already know how. )

and how do i have the ajax update the numbers in different html tags without refreshing the whole page?

example numbers would be like:

use:13129
open:9382309
people:2932938

and they automatically update themselves every, say, 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best way to fire 3 second intervals to update numbers. But to give you a direction, here is a small example:

HTML:

```
<div id="use"></div>
<div id="open"></div>
<div id="people"></div>
```

PHP for your return data:

```
$data = array('use' => rand(0,50), 'open' => rand(0,1000), 'people' => rand(0,50000));
echo json_encode($data);
```

JS:

```
function updateNumbers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourfile.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#use').html(data.use);
            $('#open').html(data.open);
            $('#people').html(data.people);
        }
    });
}

var numberUpdate = setInterval(updateNumbers, 3000);
```

This code will return 3 values with random generated numbers, provided via JSON. I think you can start from here.

Edit: For your color flashing effect:

Download the colors plugin and link it in the dom (right after jQuery script tag): https://github.com/edwinm/Color-animation-jQuery-plugin/blob/master/jquery.animate-colors-min.js

Example usage:

```
$('#use').html(data.use).css('color', '#ff0000').animate({color:#000});
```

This will cause starting with red color `#ff0000` and transists to black `#000`.

If you want flashing text only when numbers get changed, extend the updateNumbers function to something like that:

```
function updateNumbers() {
    var currentUse =  !isNaN(parseInt($('#use').html())) ? parseInt($('#use').html()) : 0;
    var currentOpen = !isNaN(parseInt($('#open').html())) ? parseInt($('#open').html()) : 0;
    var currentPeople = !isNaN(parseInt($('#people').html())) ? parseInt($('#people').html()) : 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourfile.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            if (currentUse != parseInt(data.use))
                $('#use').html(data.use).css('color', '#ff0000').animate({color:#000});

            if (currentOpen!= parseInt(data.open))
                $('#open').html(data.open).css('color', '#ff0000').animate({color:#000});

            if (currentPeople != parseInt(data.people))
                $('#people').html(data.people).css('color', '#ff0000').animate({color:#000});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the php file will cache the data for 3 seconds is what i meant, sorry for the misunderstanding. And thank you for the code, i think that might be the exact codes i'm looking for. i'll test it later.

Comment: by the way, do you happen to know how do i color the text each time it gets updated?  i've seen that often but don't know how it work. when an update comes(the 3 seconds ajax interval)the text blinks a color, say, green, and then fades back to its original color.

Comment: You can use the jQuery colors plugin: https://github.com/edwinm/Color-animation-jQuery-plugin. With this you can do effects like: `$('#use').html(data.use).css('color', '#ff0000').animate({color:#000});` This will start with red and then fades back to black. This is one possibility to do. There are many more.

Comment: my intention was when a number is updated(new data), then it does the animation thing, if its the same data as last time, dont color it. also, is there a simpler/standalone coloring/animating js or script or code for me to use? i'm not sure on how to use the one you gave me. and i got the ajax updating part working, really appreciate it.

Comment: simply download the colors plugin as minifield: https://github.com/edwinm/Color-animation-jQuery-plugin/blob/master/jquery.animate-colors-min.js and use my example above. It's really easy. The task isn't as simple as you think. If values doesn't change, you can check them first. I edited my answer for the text effect.

Comment: everything working perfectly as i intended, thank you so much. and just one small detail, how do i pre-fetch the numbers? say if i wanted the numbers to be there when the page loads instead of waiting for whatever interval is set to update them.

Comment: Just echo the array as json encoded string into the html file in a script tag: `<script>var numbers = <?php echo json_encode($dataArray);?>; $('#use').html(numbers.use); // and so on...</script>` or call the function updateNumbers(); directly in `$(document).ready(function(){updateNumbers();});`

Comment: another quick question after 3 months: if i were to use your code inside another set of program/function/system, how do i use them with the jquery no conflict, because at the moment, when i apply the codes in my current system, the numbers doesn't get updated, and some other things, like a drop down menu, doesnt drop down when hovered. it happened before with jquery codes, but i forgot how to fix it, i've tried multiple ways to use the noconflict thing, still no joy.

Comment: Hard to say. Do you have an example?

Comment: is there anyway i can message you privately?